# how to move one div with another in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am trying to make a web app with two boxes, one contained in the other. The user should be able to click and move the inner box, however, the user should not be able to move this box outside the confines of the outer box. The user can move the outer box by dragging the inner box against one of the edges of the outer box. I know how to move the inner box, but the problem is how to move the other box with this restriction. Can anybody help me please? Here is what I did so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Game</title>
<style>
#container {
height:400px;
width:600px;
outline: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top: 0px;
background-color:green;
}
#guy {
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:50px;
outline: 1px solid black;
background-color:red;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="guy"></div>
<script>
var guy=document.getElementById("guy");
var cont=document.getElementById("container");
var lastX,lastY; // Tracks the last observed mouse X and Y position


guy.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 1) {
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
      addEventListener("mousemove", moved);
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent selection
    }
  });

function buttonPressed(event) {
    if (event.buttons == null)
      return event.which != 0;
    else
      return event.buttons != 0;
  }
  function moved(event) {
    if (!buttonPressed(event)) {
      removeEventListener("mousemove", moved);
    } else {
      var distX = event.pageX - lastX;
      var distY = event.pageY - lastY;    
      guy.style.left =guy.offsetLeft + distX  + "px";
      guy.style.top = guy.offsetTop + distY  + "px";
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
    }
  }

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check to see if moving the box would break bounds of cont.

try to use **getBoundingClientRect()**

***Check the snippet below for the working code.***

View in full screen for best results.

```js
var guy=document.getElementById("guy");
var cont=document.getElementById("container");
var lastX,lastY; // Tracks the last observed mouse X and Y position


guy.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 1) {
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
      addEventListener("mousemove", moved);
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent selection
    }
  });

function buttonPressed(event) {
    if (event.buttons == null)
      return event.which != 0;
    else
      return event.buttons != 0;
  }
  function moved(event) {
    if (!buttonPressed(event)) {
      removeEventListener("mousemove", moved);
    } else {
      var distX = event.pageX - lastX;
      var distY = event.pageY - lastY;    
      guy.style.left =guy.offsetLeft + distX  + "px";
      guy.style.top = guy.offsetTop + distY  + "px";
     
       // ********************************************************************
      // get bounding box borders
      var contBounds = guy.getBoundingClientRect();
      var guyBounds = cont.getBoundingClientRect();
      
      // check bottom bounds
      if (contBounds.bottom >= guyBounds.bottom){
         cont.style.top = cont.offsetTop + distY  + "px";
      }
      
      // check top bounds
      if (contBounds.top <= guyBounds.top){
         cont.style.top = cont.offsetTop + distY  + "px";
      }
      
      // check left bounds
      if (contBounds.left <= guyBounds.left){
         cont.style.left = cont.offsetLeft + distX  + "px";
      }
      
      // check right bounds
      if (contBounds.right >= guyBounds.right){
         cont.style.left = cont.offsetLeft + distX  + "px";
      }
      // ********************************************************************
      
      lastX = event.pageX;
      lastY = event.pageY;
    }
  }
```

```css
#container {
height:300px;
width:300px;
outline: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top: 0px;
background-color:#CCC;
}
#guy {
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:50px;
outline: 1px solid black;
background-color:#000;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="guy"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your "if" statements don't work well, I have tried lots of if statements, no luck so far

Comment: Fixed and if i understand what you wanted this works. Give it a go in the snippet.

Comment: @Icewine solution works for me too, may be it's your browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this link to get you started as far as keeping the "guy" inside the "contatiner": http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
their example shows how you can make an element only drop inside another element.

as far as moving the container...i would *think* that you could add some if else statements into the moved function that will test the position of the guy against the conatiner's outline and say that when they meet to move the container as well.

i am very new to javascript myself but this is just a suggestion from what i think i understand of it.